# angularjs: multiple abstract states, redirecting issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to merge two abstract states view into one state. Below is my code. Problem is when I go to `.../#!/app/user/27/settings` it redirect me to `.../#!/app/user/27` not stay at user settings.

**Angular version 1.6.4**

App.js:

```
module.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) 
{

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
    $stateProvider

        .state("app", {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/app",
            component: "appRouting"
        })


        .state("app.user", {
            url: "/user/:userId",
            component: "userProfileRouting"
        })

        .state("user", {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/user/:userId",
            component: "userRouting"
        })

        .state("app.user.settings", {
            url: "/settings",
            //component: "userSettingsRouting"
            template: "hello"
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting scenario, here is the solution:

As you can check in [Angularjs Nested states: 3 level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21818515/139637) nesting is possible.

The problem arrives on how angular does the routing, mainly in how `ui-view` is used to render the routing. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16822559/139637) problem.

The key point is that your state `app.user` has to have a `ui-view` wrapping:

```
<div ui-view>
  ...component code
</div>
```

Please check the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Djc32l?p=preview) I created to describe the solution.

Main attention to the `contact.detail.html` content.